# Compare two arrays in javascript with specific ID

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking for a cleaner and more efficient solution in javascript to compare two arrays and create a third one.

So I have two arrays :

```
var array1 = [
    [{
    id: 1,
    enabled: false

  }],
  [{
    id: 2,
    enabled: true,
  }],
  [{
    id: 10,
    enabled: false
  }]
]

var array2 = [
    {
    id_from_array1: 10,
    data: true
  },
  {
    id_from_array1: 20,
    data: false
  },
  {
    id_from_array1: 1,
    data: true
  }
]
```

And i want to extract from the second array the IDs that are not present in the first array, so for now my solution is to create a third array with a double loop to compare the values ​​of the first two arrays :

```
var array3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < array1.length; y++) {
      if (array2[i].id_from_array1 === array1[y][0].id) {
        array3.push(array2[i])
    }
  }
}
```

[the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spitfire378/eLpkfqnr/)

can we do better ?

Thx!

Comment: By extract I meant delete, and by better I mean indeed with less code and more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of `id` from array1 then `.filter` the array 2 based on the previous id array;

```
var ids = array1.map( el => el[0].id );
ids = Array.from(new Set(ids)); // Get unique ids as set are always unique
var array3 = array2.filter( el => ids.indexOf(el.id_from_array1)!==-1);
console.log(array3);
```

```js
var array1 = [
    [{
    id: 1,
    enabled: false

  }],
  [{
    id: 2,
    enabled: true,
  }],
  [{
    id: 10,
    enabled: false
  }]
]

var array2 = [
    {
    id_from_array1: 10,
    data: true
  },
  {
    id_from_array1: 20,
    data: false
  },
  {
    id_from_array1: 1,
    data: true
  }
];

var ids = array1.map( el => el[0].id );
var array3 = array2.filter( el => ids.indexOf(el.id_from_array1)!==-1);
console.log(array3);
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, luckily, I can indeed use ES6 in my project 
without transpilers, I'm going to compare performance on big data

Comment: @spitfire378 sure :)

Comment: @spitfire378 check the slight optimization I did. Now I am picking the unique ids from array1.

Comment: Nice @void thx, your last optimization significantly increases performance on the big data I'm processing

Answer (score 0):

you can use find function as follows:

```
var array3 = [];
array2.find(function(element1) {
  var matched = array1.find(function(element2) {
    return element2[0].id == element1.id_from_array1;
  });
  if (matched != null) array3.push(matched);
});
```